# Scroll UI Image

Tags: unity, unity-ui

Currently, I am scrolling a UI `RawImage` using the following:

```
[SerializeField] private RawImage _imageToScroll;
[SerializeField] private float _x, _y;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    _imageToScroll.uvRect = new Rect(_imageToScroll.uvRect.position + new Vector2(_x, _y) * Time.deltaTime, _imageToScroll.uvRect.size);
}
```

However, I'd like to use a regular `Image`, rather than `RawImage`.
The reason I'd like to switch to using a regular Image is because I need to tile an image to fill the dialogue box below:

[image]

From what I can tell, RawImage doesn't seem to allow for tiling the way Image does. Is there a similar and simple way to accomplish this scrolling effect with `Image`?

Comment: Can you clarify why you're unable to use a RawImage here? The only way I know to do it with an Image component would be to create a custom material and use that to shift the texture coordinates.

Comment: I'm more than happy to! I've updated my initial post with the specifics. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with RawImage just fine.

- In your Project folder, select the texture that you want to tile.

  - Set its Wrap Mode to Repeat.
- Then select your RawImage.

  - Set its UV Rect W and H parameters to the number of tile repeats you want, horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Oh, this makes things much easier! Just tried it out and it works perfectly. Thank you!